# Creating an auto-increment column in Lists which resets when value changes in another Column

Tags: list, id

I'm new to Sharepoint lists and I'm trying to do this below task:

I have a "Module" column which has values like SAL,MAR,AUD
I need ID column which should auto-generate values like SAL_001,SAL_002,MAR_**001**,MAR_002

Basically I need the ID column to generate 001,002,003.... for each module

I tried an ID solution with Power Automate but the ID doesn't reset for each module.

Answer (score 0):

The ID column is auto-generated and doesn't depend on any particular column value. It's basically an identifier that helps in fetching the particular list item.

**Solution** - You can create a separate column in the list of type "Single Line of Text" and in the Power Automate, Add a Get Items action to get items from the same list having the same module name provided in the filter query.
Update the created item column value by this formula -

```
ModuleName + Length of items, i.e. SAL1
```

The item count returned will help you in identifying the module items length and you can use it for setting up the indexing column value.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I have an additional Condition. Suppose I delete an item from between and then add a new Item then the indexing shouldn't change. 
Example:
JAN001
JAN002
JAN003

Suppose I delete JAN 002 and add a new item, the index now should be like
JAN001
JAN003
JAN004.

Can you suggest something

Comment: Then you can keep a separate list i.e. `ModuleItemCountList` with two columns `1. ModuleName, 2. ItemCount` and store the count of list items acc. to modules. Now, whenever you're creating new item, refer to the list count, add 1 and update the column. Also, increment the ItemCount value in `ModuleItemCountList` list.